# Remove leading zeros in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on this project. The user will need to scan in two barcodes. The first barcode will initiate a lookup to populate a few fields in the report, and the second barcode is simply populated to the report.

My problem is both barcodes have leading zeros in them and if I included the zeros in the report, there would not be enough space on the report.

The first barcode consists of the following possibilities: 1. pure numbers with leading zeros 2. alpha-numeric combo without any leading zeros

The second barcode always has 5 leading zeros with it.

Anyone knows how I can only show the information on the report without any leading zeros?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those zeroes are significant.  You can't just remove them without breaking the bar code.

Answer (score 0):

The first barcode you should leave, text as it is.

The second, if numeric, you can strip for leading zeroes this way:

```
StrippedBarcode = CStr(Val(ScannedBarcode))
```